# Alternating and absolute convergence

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

Consider the alternating series: 
sin (x) = x - x^3 / 3! + x^5 / 5! ....

If we approximate sin(x) ≈ x, then

|x - sin (x) | < | answer |

What would be the answer, I tried various methods, but all of them led to wrong answers. Please do explain the working.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose that is around 0. 
$\sin(x)-x=-x^3/3!+x^5/5!-...=o(x^3)$ and then your answer is $x^3$

Comment: But won't be x^3 be too small. I get it that it will be smaller than x^3 but same could be said for other terms like (x^3-x^5) or so. And why is 3! not taken into account?
Thanks!

Comment: The answer is actually x^3/3!, still can you explain why x^5 term is not taken into account?

Comment: If x\in(-\epsilon,\epsilon), really don't make a difference :6